# OL Static Image with dynamic extent

Tags: openlayers, extents, image, static

I use the Static Image function to display static images as a overlay in a map. The images are loaded by click OL feature points in the map. The problem is, the images have different width/height.

Currently, I have put the static image overlay map functions in an `image.onload` event and get the width/height inside of this for the `imageExtent`. Because of this, the images are loaded two times. The good thing is, the browsers request the images for the second time from the cache. But in common sense, the two-time loading is not so good.

Have anyone an idea to get the image with/height for `imageExtent` with only one image loading?

Here is the Static Image example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/static-image.html

```
function myfunc(filename) {
    
    var imgsrc = filename;
    
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        
        var imgext = [0, 0, this.width, this.height];
        
        var imgext = [0, 0, this.width, this.height];
        
        var overlaymap = new ol.Map({
            target: 'mapoverlay',
            layers: [],
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attributionOptions: ({
                    collapsible: true,
                })
            })
        });
        
        var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
            code: 'xkcd-image',
            units: 'pixels',
            extent: imgext,
        });
        
        var view = new ol.View({
            projection: projection,
            center: ol.extent.getCenter(imgext),
            zoom: 0,
            minZoom: 0,
            maxZoom: 21
        });
        overlaymap.setView(view);
        
        var imgstatic = new ol.source.ImageStatic({
            imageLoadFunction: function(image, src) {
                                    image.getImage().src = imgsrc;
                                },
            imageExtent: imgext
        });
        
        var imglayer = new ol.layer.Image({
            source: imgstatic
        });
        overlaymap.addLayer(imglayer);
        
    }
    img.src = imgsrc;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution to load image only once is to draw it to canvas, convert canvas to data URL and set data URL as image source.

Code could then look something like this:

```
function myfunc(filename) {
  var imgsrc = filename;
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    var imgext = [0, 0, this.width, this.height];
    var overlaymap = new ol.Map({
      target: 'mapoverlay',
      layers: [],
      controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: ({
          collapsible: true,
        })
      })
    });
    var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
      code: 'xkcd-image',
      units: 'pixels',
      extent: imgext,
    });
    var view = new ol.View({
      projection: projection,
      center: ol.extent.getCenter(imgext),
      zoom: 0,
      minZoom: 0,
      maxZoom: 21
    });
    overlaymap.setView(view);
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    var imageDataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    var imgstatic = new ol.source.ImageStatic({
      url: imageDataURL
      imageExtent: imgext
    });
    var imglayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: imgstatic
    });    overlaymap.addLayer(imglayer);
  }
  img.src = imgsrc;
}
```

Comment: Please give a hint that for `url:` also a `DataURL` can be used. (Possibly a hint to the source code).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. Is answer not clear? What is missing?

Comment: I haven't found a hint anywhere that a `DataURL` can also be used with `url:`. Is it a self made up solution that works or is it a valid solution?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "self made up solution" or "valid solution". It's a solution that works. As for your comment "I haven't found a hint anywhere that a DataURL can also be used with url:", that's the main purpose of data URL: to be used as valid URL. Here is one of the thousands of references: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: That is not to what i point. I point to what can used by `url:`. I have found yet that: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/13703

Comment: I have tested your code: `Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure.`  `var imageDataURL = canvas.toDataURL();` is wrong inside `onload`.

Comment: This is so called CORS error. See more about that here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: OK. Thanks for the info. I have moved the files to the same site. Your solution works, but its perceptible slower than the two-time image loading. Its hard to mark it as the solution. I will don't use it.

Comment: The above answer is answer to your question "Have anyone an idea to get the image with/height for imageExtent with only one image loading?" There was no requirement about efficiency.

Comment: When you have an idea for a solution with more efficiency, please tell it.

Comment: here is a solution with better performance: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14514

Comment: If you found more efficient solution, then publish it as answer to your own question.